# function of class $C^r $

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x,y)=f(x,y)+(f(x,y))^5$. If $f$ is continuous and $g$ is class $C^r$, show that $f$ is a function of class $C^r$ and calculate $df/dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\phi:t \mapsto t+t^5$  for $t \in \mathbb R$ is monotonically increasing, thus invertible. It is also smooth ($C^\infty$), and by the inverse function theorem $\phi^{-1}$ is smooth as well.

Now, since $g=\phi \circ f$ we have $f= \phi^{-1} \circ g$, which is the composition of two $C^r$ functions (in fact the first is even $C^\infty$ as mentioned earlier). The chain rule shows that $f$ is of class $C^r$ as well.

As for $\frac{df}{dx}$, differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+5f^4 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, $$ and this equation can be solved easily.